# How can i make my batch script to write a new text file every time it is executed?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script. I want that the batch script should overwrite the existing file but it should not overwrite the for loop entries ?

PFB the content of batch file :

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do call ec2-describe-snapshots --filter "volume-id=%%s">>%EC2_HOME%\Snapshots.txt
```

I want a new text file everytime I execute the script.Also I want it should not  overwrite the entry of a previous for loop variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a single arrow

```
>
```

It will overwrite the file, or if you use multiple arrows

```
>>
```

It will append to the file.

So, use a > for the first for loop, and >> for subsequent loops

Comment: but i also want to delete the text files when the first time script executes? how can i do that. means i want put that delete statement in the first line of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    rem Remove file contents
    break > %EC2_HOME%\Snapshots.txt

    for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do (
        call ec2-describe-snapshots --filter "volume-id=%%s" >> %EC2_HOME%\Snapshots.txt
    )
```

Or,

```
(
    for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do (
        call ec2-describe-snapshots --filter "volume-id=%%s"
    )
) > %EC2_HOME%\Snapshots.txt
```